# Samba Clients set up

Tags: samba, configuration, workgroup

OK, I've learned how to use nano to edit smb.conf file with some limited success.
How do I set up each client machine to use Samba? Does the workgroup definition in the config file refer to the same networking workgroup of my windows machines?  I'm running 12.04lts by the way.  I need the baby steps if you please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the [global] section of the smb.conf file add:

```
wins support = yes
name resolve order = lmhosts hosts bcast wins
workgroup = "Name of workgroup" #usually WORKGROUP in Windows
security = user
```

Then, if you want users to be able to browse files, you need to add a share:

```
[Share]
     comment = Network Share
     path = /home/share
     create mask = 0700
     directory mask = 0700
     guest ok = yes
     browseable = yes
     writable = yes
```

Then restart samba:

```
sudo restart smbd
sudo restart nmbd
```

Or:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart
sudo /etc/init.d/smbd restart
```

Edit:  [Here is the link](http://www.maketecheasier.com/install-and-configure-samba-in-ubuntu-for-file-sharing/) I was talking about in my comment

Comment: Thanks ChrisR, I did as you said in your post and got a successful edit of the Samba config file.  I used nano as my line editor.  The problem is that my client windows machine cannot "see" my Linux server except throught the router utility.  Network neighborhood does not have my server showing up, yet I can ssh into the server via putty.  honestly I am surprised I've made it thus far.  Stuck now.

Comment: You can try restarting your machine and see if that helps.  I also added an additional command to the original answer, along with a link that gives some tips and has a link to a GUI way of doing it.